# Cache-Control and Pragma Response headers while reading files from Data Lakes

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-data-lake

Why do we get the below 2 headers while trying to read files stored in Azure Data Lake using REST API?

**Cache-Control →no-cache, no-cache, no-store, max-age=0  (Why do we have multiple no-cache)
Pragma →no-cache**

Why are these Headers getting set and How can we override them such them we can cache the responses ?

*Below is my curl request*
*curl -v -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6IlJyUXF1OXJ5ZEJWUldtY29jdVhVYjIwSEdSTSIsImtpZCI6IlJyUXF1OXJ5ZEJWUldtY29jdVhVYjIwSEdSTSJ9.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.TrkCayxF0MJbXe7SPc8ZtMx8Aw07Plv0PE1KDAUw1hjHBgmTE95y0ivA2qKpmkvbLkreaGICmzc-4DPNcPBgQFHaiHzS9MoiC6c0mOO_0oOw7FRsbDYnL-P03_MEoHYDas7o2BC88ruZlHHePmoOHqwwXwBOgr6si5RwRmFz7InJpfILqENKD-fk2uWBWfQ1JU3xvmVLUgeoToFK-q7Xs
g6eHgW84S4gGF7xuvjz2ogduxmhaV18A80rFFRFk70uHXllFcDylHKXPqgRJ9dfHswZEczxQSQCI2hH5XTn72xMUI0ygIFX4mPjwPQhxPAaygMLxYBOhG5gNm1vBAsJww" "https://signstorage.azuredatalakestore.net/webhdfs/v1/signsdata/test.txt?op=OPEN&api-version=2016-11-01&read=true"*

**Response**
**File contents and Response Headers are** 
*HTTP/1.1 200 OK
**Cache-Control: no-cache, no-cache, no-store, max-age=0
Pragma: no-cache**
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Expires: -1
x-ms-request-id: 302fd601-0eca-4db0-a2de-cc2ee5d951d8
x-ms-webhdfs-version: 16.07.18.01
Status: 0x0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains
Date: Thu, 08 Dec 2016 06:27:31 GMT*

Comment: As I known, the Cache-Control is used to control the browsers for caching the individual responses. which side (your server-side , browser, etc.) do you want to cache this response? Please provide more details about your scenario.

Comment: @Bruce-MSFT : cache-control can be for any caching mechanisms may that be browser or any client app ..
no-cache-should always reach the origin server
no-store-cache should not store

My scenario is
1.Client requests a file through Azure CDN and requested file is served from nearest geographical edge cache server.
2.If File is not cached in edge server then get it from data lake storage and cache it in edge.

My query is how to remove/override cache-control headers from its default.Even 'Force-caching' on Azure CDN does not work for this response.

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, ADLS doesn't support caching mechanisms, hence the headers that you see are sent by the service to limit caching.

Thank you,
Guy